# Factoring and distributing exponents

Tags: exponentiation, factoring

When you have an expression like:

```
(x + 2)^2
```

it actually means:

```
(x + 2)*(x + 2)
```

But how come you can't just distribute the exponent directly like:

```
x^2 + 2^2 = x^2 + 4
```

?

Comment: Did you try with actual numbers? Is $(1 + 2)^2$ the same as $1^2 + 2^2$?

Comment: @T. Bongers I know that the two expression's don't equal, I'm asking for the mathematical reason as to *why* you can't distribute the exponent like that.

Comment: Because they mean completely different things. Is a $3 \times 3$ square the same as a $1 \times 1$ square combined with a $2 \times 2$ square? A better question to ask would be: Why *would* they be the same?

Comment: @T.Bongers ok i see thanks

Comment: I'm tempted to mention fields of characteristic $p$ and the [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream), but when looking at the level of the question, feel like it will only confuse the OP.

Comment: Multiplication distributes over addition and subtraction. It's practically the only distribution law that actually works. Almost no other two operations behave that way. So really, a better question would be this: why does multiplication distribute over addition and subtraction? That can actually be proved from the Peano axioms. See Landau Fundamentals of Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+2)^2=(x+2)\times (x+2)=(x+2)\times x+(x+2)\times 2=(x^2+2x)+(2x+4)$$